# ListBox ,ScrollViewer и CanContentScroll

Tags: .net, wpf

I have ListBox with ScrollViewer

```
<ScrollViewer Focusable="False" CanContentScroll="True"                     
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">            
         <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="False">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                    
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"/>                        
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border CornerRadius="3,3,3,3">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <myControls:MyControl/>
                                    </Grid>    
                                </Border>     
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>        
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">                                    
                                <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" CanContentScroll="True">
                                    <Border>                                           
                                        <StackPanel Margin="2"           Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>                                                                           
                                    </Border>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
        </ListBox>           
    </ScrollViewer>
```

But CanContentScroll="True" does't work.  It's still scrolling in physical units. 
Whats wrong in my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the Border between your ScrollViewer and your StackPanel, which is preventing the ScrollViewer from finding the StackPanel.  StackPanel implements the IScrollInfo interface to do logical scrolling, but if ScrollViewer can't find an IScrollInfo child it falls back to doing physical scrolling.

There are three ways to obtain logical scrolling inside a ScrollViewer:

1. Let the ScrollViewer's *direct child* be a panel that can do logical scrolling (such as a StackPanel)
2. Let the ScrollViewer's *direct child* be an ItemsPresenter which presents such a panel
3. Let the ScrollViewer's *direct child* be a custom class you write yourself that implements IScrollInfo

**The simple solutions**

The first two solutions are self-explanatory, but I want to point out that using an ItemsPresenter is probably a better idea than directly including your StackPanel in your template.  That way other ListBoxes in your solution can take advantage of your ControlTemplate without being forced into using an identical panel.  In other words, I would do something like this instead of what you wrote:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin="2" Orientation="Horizontal" ... />
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

  <ListBox.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer Focusable="False" CanContentScroll="True">   
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

**The advanced technique**

If really need to display a border around a logically-scrolling StackPanel but have that border appear to scroll with the data, you'll have to do some additional plumbing.  When a StackPanel is doing logical scrolling, the StackPanel itself scrolls its contents during arrange and the ScrollViewer doesn't do any actual scrolling at all (it just manages scrollbars, etc).  You'll find that StackPanel adamantly refuses to scroll anything that isn't actually one of its Children, so unless your border can be an actual ListBox item, you need to fake things out a bit.

To make it look like a Border is being scrolled along with the StackPanel contents:

1. Create a "CompoundScrolling" custom control to manage it that implements IScrollInfo.
2. Give your "CompoundScrolling" control a template that includes a Grid.
3. In the Grid put a Border and StackPanel, with the Border in back and suitable margins on the StackPanel.
4. Implement all the IScrollInfo properties and methods by calling equivalent methods on the StackPanel (you can give it a PART_ name and find it in OnApplyTemplate)
5. Whenever IScrollInfo methods are proxied and also in OnMeasure, OnArrange, etc, check the StackPanel's scrolling state and update the Border's position to match.

Detecting the StackPanel's scrolling state can be done by calling ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex on 0 and Items.Count-1, then checking the positioning of those containers within the StackPanel to see if they are visible.  If so, the top and bottom (or left and right for Orientation=Horizontal) sides of your Border should be visible, otherwise they should not be.  The other sides will, of course, always be visible.